# How to create a button inside a lottie animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, lottie

I am working on a very simple game in which I will play different JSON files on some button click. So for this, I need a button inside a Lottie animation view. Is this possible to set button inside a Lottie animation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of it's possible, try it out. What is always possible is to wrap everything into a FrameLayout and overlay the first view with your button.

Comment: Hi, this didn't work for me. I've wrapped a Lottie animation view and Button into a FrameLayout, and button is always on top of the animation. What I want is the Button to unwind from beneath the animation ;/